# Could not validate drop down list of content page using java script in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am using drop down list in content page , so i want to validate drop down list for selectedIndex!=0 ;

Thanks in advance
N Mahesh Goud

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the question

Comment: would you bother posting the javascript code you tried ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clientID` property,suppose your dropdownlist id is dropID then acess like this:

```
document.getElementById ("<%= dropID.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: s i am using in the same way and also used document.getelementbytagname("input") too

Comment: is your js file is External JS.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function validate() 
        {
            var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>');
            var dropdownlist = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            if (dropdownlist.selectedIndex == 0) 
            {
                alert('hi');
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        
        }
    </script> here it goesmy script

Comment: instead of "dropdownlist.selectedIndex==0" check with "ddl.selectedIndex==0".

Comment: yes it is working fine with asp drop down list buti am using third party control RadDrop  down list to  it its not  working